# macbook 13" and the audio jack for sound input

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I've followed the instructions at [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3625) to set the audio port for input, yet nothing changes as described in bullet 6.

Any idea what I could try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

It seem that the trick in the above link only works if a line in is actually connected. Which wasn't the case...